# OpenTSDB logarithmic output

Tags: logging, request, opentsdb

How to force the scale of OpenTSDB graph (output data) to logarithmic scale?
there is definitely one checkbox in OpenTSDB UI. It makes it by adding a *ylog* key to the request. 
I did not seem to be able to find this in the TSDB docs anywhere. 
Any clues on how to make a proper request like OpenTSB UI does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenTSDB currently doesn't support that kind of data transform on queries, but recent versions are slowly improving the query language (with [exp](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/exp.html) and [gexp](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/gexp.html) endpoints), so that one day that **may** be possible.

What that checkbox does is just configuring the [graphing backend](http://www.gnuplot.info/) to draw a logarithmic scale, as explained in the [docs](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/guis/index.html).

OpenTSDB itself doesn't have a graphing API, but you could use [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with understanding of architecture. 
OpenTSDB logarithmic scale is handled entirely in UI. So one should do the same. It has no way of outputting Logarithmic data.